# Why does an analytic function $z^2$, which satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, not satisfy the condition of being harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, cauchy-riemann-equations

Why does an analytic function $z^2$, which satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, not satisfy the condition of being harmonic?

We have $u = x^2-y^2$ and $v = 2xy$

\begin{align}
du/dx &= 2x, &du/dy &= -2y\\
dv/dx &= 2y, &dy/dy &= 2x
\end{align}
Which satisfies the condition such that $du/dx = dv/dy$ and $dv/dy = -dv/dx$.

I am asked to prove that $u$ and $v$ are each harmonic functions of $x$ and $y$.

but when I take the second derivative $d^2u/dx^2 = 2$, $d^2u/dy^2 = -2$, which both when added together equal to zero. So $u$ is harmonic.

BUT v is not because $dv^2/dy^2 = 2$ and $dv^2/dx^2$ is 2, which when added together are not equal to 0.

An analytic function should satisfy these conditions and I seem to do it right.

Any hints?

I am asked to prove that u and v are each harmonic functions of x and y.

Comment: You got your second partials for $v$ wrong as they are both zero

Comment: I can't seem to see why are they wrong. can you show me?

Comment: $\frac\partial{\partial x}(2xy)=2y$, $\frac\partial{\partial x}(2y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! makes sense now.